# Dart http post issue with authorization header

Tags: http, dart

Failing to add authorization header:

```
**final response = await http.post('http://rscu.gx.uz/app',
      headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "token"
      },
      body: body).then((result) {
        var body = result.body;
        debugPrint(body);
});**
```

Returned result:

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"error_code":101,"error_msg":"LANG_WRONG_API_KEY","host":"rscu.gx.uz","method":"{","params":[]}}